# Leaving Windows server folder writable after removing Authenticated Users without needing Admin escalation

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2016

On Windows Server 2016, I've created a folder that, at one point, had the following permissions on it:

[image]

At that time, when I right-clicked within the folder in Windows Explorer, I'd see this:

[image]

However, not all domain users are allowed access to this folder, so I removed the Authenticated Users group. I gave full control to another user group, ____ Developers (first word omitted for security purposes), of which I'm a member (I'm also an administrator on this server), thus:

[image]

Now, the New command on the Explorer context menu looks like this:

[image]

So, now, the only option it gives me for New is a new folder--and it wants me to give administrator authorization for that. (I am also in the local server's Administrators group.)

Further, when I try to copy files to this folder, I'm prompted to provide administrator permission. When I open a file in this folder in Notepad++, I can't save it without reopening Notepad++ in Administrator mode.

I verified on the folder's properties' Security tab that the "Effective Access" for my account is, indeed, full control. So why doesn't it just let me create and copy files without having to escalate to administrator every time? Why does it matter which group that I'm a member of has access to the folder? Is the only way to have all "New" options displayed, and to save a file without having to escalate to Admin access, to include the Authenticated Users group?

Is there a way around this obstacle?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you would have to do one of two things:

1. Explicitly grant access to either your user, or a group you are a part of.
2. Disable User Account Control. Do know that disabling UAC has a very real potential to be risky (this is different than "elevate without prompting").

By default, processes run under a less privileged security context, disabling administrative functions unless necessary to elevate. This helps to keep the principle of least privilege at play, even when working with administrative users.